# Creating names array in cakephp dropdown list

Tags: html, arrays, select, cakephp-1.3

I have created a dropdown list in cakephp as below :

```
$city_list = $form->select("GalStore.gal_location_id", $gal_locations,null,$city_attributes);
```

Now I needed to send the names of the list in a array, ie in `<select name="mylist[]">` format.

I tried to put `[]` in the above variable :

```
$city_list = $form->select("GalStore.gal_location_id[]", $gal_locations,null,$city_attributes);
```

But its producing `HTML` as :

```
<select name="data[GalStore][gal_location_id[]]">
```

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: you mean you need a multiple select? Or do you have multiple `$form->select`? If you have multiple form->select, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for, but this will give you the general idea.

```
$city_list = $form->select("GalStore.gal_location_id.0", $gal_locations,null,$city_attributes); 
// or
$city_list = $form->select("GalStore.0.gal_location_id", $gal_locations,null,$city_attributes);
```

change the `0`, as needed.